# Как получить элемент с аттрибутом data-action?

Tags: jquery

Есть элемент

```
<span class="datepicker--button" data-action="apply">Применить</span>
```

Нужно передать его в переменную button. Как это сделать

```
let button = $('[data-action="apply"]');
```

Не работает

Весь код

```
$(function(){

  $(function addApplyButton() {
    let isPickerButtons = $('#date-picker').find('.datepicker--buttons');
    if (isPickerButtons) {
      isPickerButtons.append('<span class="datepicker--button" data-action="apply">Применить</span>');
    }
  });
  addApplyButton();

  let isApplyButton = $('[data-action="apply"]');
  console.log(isApplyButton);

});
```

функция addApplyButton(); добавляет кнопку, но console.log(isApplyButton) ничего не выводит

Comment: Работает всё. Что вы делаете в дальнейшем с этой переменной?

Comment: просто хочу вывести в консоль console.log(button);

Comment: Добавьте чуток разметки.

Comment: Оно и делает то, что должно. Если хочется получить HTML элемента, один из способов `console.log( $('[data-action="apply"]')[0].outerHTML );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так Попробуйте.

```js
$(function(){

  function addApplyButton() {
    let isPickerButtons = $('#date-picker').find('.datepicker--buttons');
    if (isPickerButtons.length > 0) {
      isPickerButtons.append('<span class="datepicker--button" data-action="apply">Применить</span>');
    }
  };
  
  addApplyButton();

  let isApplyButton = $('[data-action="apply"]');
  console.log(isApplyButton);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Проверил ваш код, работает. Поменял в нём условие на своё, работает... Лишние скобки $() у function